# Apache rewrite causes infinite recursion if subdirectory is requested

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that works most of the time. However, if I request a page with a subdirectory that doesn't exist, and the subdirectory matches an existing file, it causes infinite recursion.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This works if I request:

- `test.php`
- `test` (it serves test.php)
- `badname.php` or `badname` (gives 404 correctly)
- `directory/file_that_exists` or `directory/file_that_exists.php`

All work. But if `test.php` exists, and I request `test/test`, it causes infinite recursion. The error log looks like this:

```
[Wed May 23 08:16:28.176564 2018] [core:debug] [pid 27054] core.c(3620): [client 0.0.0.0:57764] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /test/test.php.php.php
[Wed May 23 08:16:28.176566 2018] [core:debug] [pid 27054] core.c(3620): [client 0.0.0.0:57764] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /test/test.php.php
[Wed May 23 08:16:28.176568 2018] [core:debug] [pid 27054] core.c(3620): [client 0.0.0.0:57764] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /test/test.php
[Wed May 23 08:16:28.176570 2018] [core:debug] [pid 27054] core.c(3620): [client 0.0.0.0:57764] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /test/test
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't it fail when it sees that `test/test.php` doesn't exist? (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`) I get the same result if I simply append a slash, like `test/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it fail when it sees that `test/test.php` doesn't exist? (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`) I get the same result if I simply append a slash, like `test/`

It would fail if that was the check being performed, but it's not.

The `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable contains the filesystem path *after* the URL has been mapped to the filesystem. This is not necessarily the same as the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against.

For example, in your case, when requesting `/test/test.php` where there is no physical subdirectory called `/test`, the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable contains a string of the form `/absolute/filesystem/path/to/test` (ie. the requested URL up to the last known directory + the first path segment `/test`). And the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* will be `/test/test.php` (to which you will repeatedly append `.php` because `/test.php` does exist, as checked by the preceding `RewriteCond` directive).

You can resolve this by checking the URL-path instead (building an absolute filesystem path to check), much like @shanew suggests. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

An optimisation, to avoid all those filesystem checks for every request would be to include a check for the `.php` extension (and `.css`, `.js`, etc.) first, before checking to see if the files exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This avoids unnecessary checks when the requested URL already ends with `.php`, `.css`, etc.

Comment: I accepted this because it's the answer, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around why. I don't understand the part where "`REQUEST_FILENAME` contains a string of the form `/absolute/filesystem/path/to/test` (ie. the requested URL up to the last known directory + the first path segment `/test`)". The docs say "Depending on the value of `AcceptPathInfo`, the server may have only used some leading components of the `REQUEST_URI` to map the request to a file.". Is that why, or am I just off in the wrong direction? Regardless, I never would have figured this out, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a Directory section or .htaccess file, you should be able to stop the infinite recursion by adding the END option to your RewriteRule, so that it looks like this

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,END]

This stops the rewrite engine from performing any subsequent rewrite processing (whereas L just stops the current round of rewrite processing). 
The [Apache 2.4 Rewrite Flags documenation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) explains in more detail.

That said, I'm not sure this gets you the behavior you're really after, since it will still change /test/test into /test/test.php despite the fact that it doesn't exist.  To solve that, I think you need to be testing the entire file path rather than just the name of the file.  To do that, change:

> %{REQUEST_FILENAME}

into

> %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}

Additionally, to be safe, I'd add another RewriteCond  at the top so that the rule never fires if the filename already ends in .php (putting it first means the other conditions can be skipped if it returns true):

> %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "!\.php$"

Comment: You can't simply substitute `REQUEST_URI` (a document root relative URL) for `REQUEST_FILENAME` (an absolute filesystem path) in the _file exists_ check. You need to convert `REQUEST_URI` into an absolute filesystem path before doing the filesystem check, otherwise it will never match. eg. prefix with the document root: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Good point (I don't normally use the -f or -d checks).  I've edited my answer to reflect that (and escaped the backslash so it would actually appear in the extension check).